# How to Add Preflight to Tailwind CSS Added via CDN

Tags: html, css

I am trying to modify the front-end of an HTML file constructed with PHP. The front file is composed of vanilla JS and HTML, and it seems that I cannot use npm. Therefore, I added the following script to include Tailwind CSS via CDN:

html

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

I confirmed that the styles of the code, such as:

html

```html
<input type="text" class="focus:ring-blue-500 border-emerald-700">
```

are applied. However, the issue is that codes like `focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500` do not seem to take effect in the browser.

It appears that I may need to add the Preflight @tailwind base; code, but I'm not sure how to add Preflight when Tailwind is added via CDN. Are there any methods to achieve this?

In the browser, codes like `focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500` are not taking effect. It seems like I may need to add the `Preflight code @tailwind base;`. However, I'm not sure how to add Preflight when Tailwind is included via CDN. Are there any methods to achieve this?